# Effectiveness of heating nitrogen gas for purging moisture

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm doing an experiment where I need to limit moisture content within a resistivity cell and am planning to perform nitrogen purging before vacuum pumping the cell before each test. I want to do the tests at 25C and was recommended to heat the nitrogen gas to around 40C to improve the effectiveness of removing moisture during nitrogen purging. I was wondering what the logic behind that is since water evaporates at 100C in atmospheric pressure and how effective heating the gas is at removing moisture. Thanks.

Comment: Water *boils* at 100C.  It evaporates at any temperature.

Comment: @M.Enns so applying 40C heat at atmospheric pressure would evaporate water?

Comment: @h.a995. Assuming the nitrogen is anhydrous, yes. And higher temperature of the nitrogen will increase the *rate* of water evaporation.

Comment: Note that pump/purge cycles are more effective than purging alone.